# Binding dropdown values using knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have the below JS:

```
function RowData(Township, Range, Section,Crop, Acres) {
var self = this;

self.Township = Township;
self.Range = Range;
self.Section = Section;
self.Crop = [{ value: "1", crop: "Irrigated Corn" }, { value: "2", crop: "Irrigated Sugar Beets" }, { value: "3", crop: "Irrigated Soybeans" }, { value: "4", crop: "Irrigated Sorghum (Milo, Sudan)" }, { value: "5", crop: "Irrigated Dry Edible Beans" }, { value: "6", crop: "Irrigated Potatoes" }, { value: "7", crop: "Irrigated Alfalfa" }, { value: "8", crop: "Irrigated Small Grains" }, { value: "9", crop: "Range/Pasture/Grass (Brome, Hay, CRP)" }, { value: "10", crop: "Urban Land" }, { value: "11", crop: "Open Water" }, { value: "12", crop: "Riparian Forest and Woodlands" }, { value: "13", crop: "Wetlands" }, { value: "14", crop: "Other Agricultural Lands (Farmsteads, Feedlots, etc.)" }, { value: "15", crop: "Irrigated Sunflower" }, { value: "16", crop: "Summer Fallow" }, { value: "17", crop: "Roads" }, { value: "18", crop: "Dryland Corn" }, { value: "19", crop: "Dryland Soybeans" }, { value: "20", crop: "Dryland Sorghum" }, { value: "21", crop: "Dryland Dry Edible Beans" }, { value: "22", crop: "Dryland Alfalfa" }, { value: "23", crop: "Dryland Small Grains" }, { value: "24", crop: "Dryland Sunflower" }, { value: "25", crop: "Dryland Sugar Beets" }, { value: "26", crop: "Dryland Potatoes" }, { value: "27", crop: "Irrigated Hay" }, { value: "28", crop: "Irrigated Rotation Pasture" }];
self.Acres = Acres;
}
function PBHEPViewModel() {
var self = this;

//Present Conditions
self.present_conditions = ko.observableArray([
    new RowData()
]);
self.present_AddRow = function () {
    self.present_conditions.push(new RowData())
}
self.present_RemoveRow = function (row) { self.present_conditions.remove(row) };

//Future Conditions
self.future_conditions = ko.observableArray([
    new RowData()
]);
self.future_AddRow = function () {
    self.future_conditions.push(new RowData())
}
self.future_RemoveRow = function (row) { self.future_conditions.remove(row) };

//submit the data
self.submit_conditions = function () {

    var PC_data = ko.toJSON(self.present_conditions());
    var FC_data = ko.toJSON(self.future_conditions());

    $.post("/Home/PBHEP", { "PC": PC_data, "FC": FC_data});
}
}
ko.applyBindings(new PBHEPViewModel());
```

And my HTML is:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:future_conditions">

        <tr>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Township" data-bind="value: Township"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Range"data-bind="value: Range"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Section"data-bind="value: Section"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                 <select name="" data-bind="options: Crop, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: function (i) { return i.crop }, optionsCaption: 'Choose a Crop...'"></select>
            </td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Acres"data-bind="value: Acres"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-small btn btn-danger" type="button" data-bind="click: $root.future_RemoveRow"><i class="icon-minus-sign icon-white"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

When I do the post I have all the entire array in the crop field where i only want to post the value that has been selected.

How do I achieve this where am I going wrong.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single-select list, you use the `value` binding to write the selected value to your viewmodel.  See the note near the top of [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for details.

Try the below binding:

```
<select name="" data-bind="options: Crop, value: Crop, optionsText: 'crop', optionsCaption: 'Choose a Crop...'"></select>
```

This displays the text in the drop down as the `crop` property of your array items.  It also assigns the selected value from the drop down to the `Crop` property of the `RowData` object.

You may want to change the name of the array, Crop, to Crops or something to differentiate it from the singular property on the RowData object.  It is a little confusing, as is.

Comment: I tried to change this and I dont have anything in my drop down and is it mandatory to have the name attribute?

Comment: when i use the value:'value' it will still give the whole array in the post

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you don't have anything in your dropdown.  are you saying the dropdown is empty?  Or is a list of blanks?  I'm not sure why you're using the function to get the optionsText.  I'll modify my answer to see if that helps.

Comment: I've updated the binding above based on a closer look at your view model.  Give that a shot.

Comment: I mean when i use the value:value instead of optionsvalue:'value' I dont have anything being populated in the drop down it doesnt open

Comment: Yes that works can you help with explaining what went wrong here.I am kind of new to knock out js.

Comment: And currently I get the value as [{"Township":"23","Range":"32","Section":"33","Crop":{"value":"2","crop":"Irrigated Sugar Beets"},"Acres":"43"}] on my server side is there any way i can just get the 'value'

Comment: I believe the main issue is the use of `OptionsValue` rather than `value`.  I don't think I can provide a better explanation than the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html).  The only thing I'd point out is that the documentation on the Options binding doesn't dive into details about the Value binding, which is a part of the Options binding.  To see that, you need to look at the [Value Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) documentation, and specifically Note 1, part way down.